# geographical heat maps using lattice levelplot in R

Tags: r, dictionary, heatmap, lattice

I am trying to build up a geospatial continuous heatmap that is not bounded by counties or artificial borders using lattice, much like the [Dialect Maps](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~jakatz2/project-dialect.html) by Katz, and a bit different from the [Choropleth Challenge](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/choropleth-challenge-result.html).

So far, I'm pretty close, but am stuck trying to figure out how to avoid showing the heatmap colors in the area outside the geographical region. See the example below:

```
library(maps)
library(lattice)

# get region border coordinates for the contiguous USA
m <- map("usa")

# make a grid of latitude and longitude, and supply z-values
lons <- seq(min(m$x, na.rm=T), max(m$x, na.rm=T), length.out=30)
lats <- seq(min(m$y, na.rm=T), max(m$y, na.rm=T), length.out=30)
pts <- expand.grid(lons, lats)
names(pts) <- c("lon", "lat")
pts$z <- sin(pts$lat*pi/180) + cos(pts$lon*pi/180)

## (A) eliminate z-values outside of the USA region
# pts$z[ lat & lon outside of region ] <- NA # don't know how to do this
# this could work, but would leave jagged edges around the region border

levelplot(z~lon*lat, pts, aspect="xy",
           panel = function(...){
             panel.levelplot(...) 
             panel.xyplot(m$x, m$y, type="l", col="black") # adds USA border
             # (B) fill the area outside region with white 
             # panel.something() # not sure what to use here
          })
```

Approach (B) would probably work well, but I don't see a simple way to do this. Any thoughts?

Comment: This might be of help: http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Clearing-the-area-outside-of-a-polygon-defined-on-a-grid-td7581718.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to accomplish what you ask using `map` and `lattice`, but here's how I would go about solving your problem using `raster` and `rgeos` tools:

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)

## get SpatialPolygnsDataFrame map of the states
m <- getData("GADM", country="United States", level=1)
m <- m[!m$NAME_1 %in% c("Alaska","Hawaii"),] # sorry Alaska and Hawaii 

## here I modified your code to make a raster object
r <- raster(nrow=30, ncol=30, 
            xmn=bbox(m)["x","min"], xmx=bbox(m)["x","max"],
            ymn=bbox(m)["y","min"], ymx=bbox(m)["y","max"],
            crs=proj4string(m))
xyz <- rasterToPoints(r)
r[] <- sin(xyz[,"y"]*pi/180) + cos(xyz[,"x"]*pi/180)

## Option A) mask raster using polygon
newr <- mask(r, m)
plot(newr, col=cm.colors(60), axes=FALSE)
plot(m, add=TRUE)
box(col="white")
## leaves jagged edges...
```

[image]

```
## Option B) cover the outside area
b <- gUnaryUnion(rasterToPolygons(r)) # first create a polygon that covers the raster
b <- gDifference(b, m) # then get the difference between the polygons
plot(r, col=cm.colors(100), axes=FALSE)
plot(b, add=TRUE, col="white", border="white")
plot(m, add=TRUE)
box(col="white")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could transform 'pts' and 'm' to objects of class `Raster*` and `Spatial*`, respectively, and subsequently  use them as input for `spplot` (which is a wrapper around `levelplot`, see `?raster::spplot`). This allows you to discard exactly those pixels that should not be displayed (via `mask`) and, at the same time, ensures compatibility with further **lattice** (or **grid**) based operations. Here is some sample code.

```
## transform 'map' object to 'SpatialPolygons'
library(maptools)
m <- map2SpatialPolygons(m, IDs = seq(m$names), 
                         proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

## rasterize pts and mask pixels outside map region
library(raster)
coordinates(pts) <- ~ lon + lat
proj4string(pts) <- "+init=epsg:4326"
pts <- as(pts, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
rst <- raster(pts)
rst <- mask(rst, m)

## display data
library(latticeExtra)
spplot(rst, scales = list(draw = TRUE), alpha.regions = .8) + 
  layer(sp.polygons(m, lwd = 2))
```

[image: spplot]

In order to appropriately address edge effects, I suggest you stick to the nice workaround provided by @PaulRegular.